# "Do you have the reference number with you?" or "Do you have the reference number on you?"

Tags: grammar

> "Do you have the reference number **with** you?"

or

> "Do you have the reference number **on** you?"

Please tell me which one is correct

Answer (score 3):

"I don't have it on me" is a common thing to say in British English.

- Do you have it with you?

> If the person has travelled somewhere, and they brought it with them - they might be holding it, but it could instead be outside in their car, or someone else might be carrying it. It is still "with them" because they can get it quickly and easily. It's not at home, or far away.
>
> You might ask this for an official thing, like a reference number.
>
> "Do you have the reference number with you?"
>
> "Yes here it is" or "Yes, it's outside in my car, I'll go and get it"
>
> "Thank you"

- Do you have it on you?

> Are you carrying it yourself, in your pocket or bag? If it is outside in your car, then it is not "on you". If someone else has it, it is not "on you".
>
> You would ask this for a quick request, one that you don't want them to have to go and get something.
>
> *"You have a pocket knife - do you have it on you?"*
>
> "No, it's at my desk"
>
> *"Nevermind, don't go and get it. I'll just tear this box open"*.

Comment: there are many situations where 'on me' is possible (Hey, those hamburgers are on me -in the restaurant, I'm giving a party. Here, those food items are 'on' me means I'm paying the bill. But then, those are **not** relevant here. The OP talks about 'reference number' which for sure will take 'with' here.

Comment: No, in AmE, at least, it is not "for sure", @MaulikV we use 'do you have a/the -- on you?' all the time. By the way, +1 for careful distinction of the  two uses, which are the same in AmE. *Do you have a cigarette on you?* means *Do you have a cigarette on your person (as it were)?*

Comment: very strange to me then! :) @pazzo

Comment: **[have](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/have)** sense 3b. "to be holding something or carrying something with you"; **have something on you**: *I don’t have any money on me.*

Comment: This makes me curious about the downvote.

Comment: @MaulikV - This answer is spot on. Either one could be used; see [Collins #3](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on), or [Cambridge `POSSESSION`](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/on): *Do you have a spare pen on you? / I don't have my driving licence on me.* If I saw you write the reference number on a slip of paper, and I think you may have put that slip of paper in your pocket or wallet, there's a good chance I'd ask, "Do you have the reference number on you?"

Comment: That reminds me of guinea pigs with reference numbers 'on' their bodies! They are ready to be taken to a laboratory ;) @J.R. In such case, I'll simply ask -Do you have a reference number? Anyway, as I said, it looks odd to me.. maybe, a dialect difference.

Comment: @Maulik - I like how your answer mentioned that you could omit the prepositional phrase entirely, but I winced when you implied that _on_ shouldn't be used that way. Pick a contemporary dictionary, it's in there: [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/have-something-on-you), [M-W 2d](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on), [Dictionary.com 25](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ON), [YD 24](http://www.yourdictionary.com/on), etc. Although a couple of those dub it as `informal`, the more reputable ones don't even say that.

Comment: We also say *Can I borrow a cigarette **off** of you?* I'm using cigarette examples, because cig smokers seem to borrow and loan cigs a lot. :) As for *off of you* I can't think of another example besides cigs at the moment, although maybe money: *Can I borrow $10 off you?* @J.R. and others, any other examples or uses? Also (AmE): *Can I bum $10 off you?*

Answer (score 2):

In most of the cases, it's *"with"*. However, to think further about the subtlety of the usage of prepositions, you may have to come up with the context ["That's **on** me" -is possible when I'm talking about paying a restaurant bill].

It's a style of talking. You can also remove the whole part 'with you' in such contexts.

> Do you have the reference number (with you)? 
>  Do you have a pen (with you)? 
>  Do you have a paper (with you)? and so on...

Comment: BrE could colloquially use 'on you' for all of those, but in any more formal situation, I'd avoid it. [idk if AmE has similar usage]

Comment: [AmE does](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58026/do-you-have-the-reference-number-with-you-or-do-you-have-the-reference-numbe#comment110491_58034) @Tetsujin and others